# AJAX Post request - sending json object to node.js server

Tags: node.js, ajax

I am making an Ajax Post request:

```
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        dataType:"json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data:newWorkLog,
        url:"/add",
      })
        .done(function(response){
          console.log("Response of update: ",response)
        })
        .fail(function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
          console.log("ERROR: ",xhr.responseText)
          return xhr.responseText;
        });
```

and was expecting to pass that `newWorkLog` object to an API method through my node.js server:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.post('/add', function(req, res){
        console.log(req.body) //This doesnt output anything
        res.send(JSON.stringify(req.body));
    });
```

After trying some approaches, I decided to only check what is being sent to my server.

Doing this, the message I get is:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at createStrictSyntaxError (C:\working\app\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:157:10)
    at parse (C:\working\app\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:83:15)
    at C:\working\app\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:121:18
    at invokeCallback (C:\working\app\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
    at done (C:\working\app\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\working\app\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)
    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1055:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

When I  console.log my `newWorkLog` object, I can see from my client side, the correct json object.

when I check the param on the console I see the request payload and it looks like:

```
user%5Bid%5D=109&user%5BuserName%5D=myname
```

What could be causing that error?

Comment: In order to parse body you need to use bodyParser and you can it like this `app.use(express.bodyParser());`

Comment: I am using app.use(bodyParser.json()) I edited the question

Comment: `var express = require('express')
  , app = express.createServer();

app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.post('/', function(request, response){
  console.log(request.body);      // your JSON
  response.send(request.body);    // echo the result back
});

app.listen(3000);`

try to redefine the server

Comment: I got that error: express.createServer is not a function

Comment: `npm install express --save`

Comment: express is already installed and the server works, the only problem is when I try that post request on the question.

express.createServer() has been deprecated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167256/discussion-between-shailesh-rathod-and-fix3r).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say `newWorkLog` is an object so you need to convert it to json to send it in your request.

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    dataType:"json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data:JSON.stringify(newWorkLog),
    url:"/add",
})
.done(function(response){
      console.log("Response of update: ",response)
})
.fail(function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
      console.log("ERROR: ",xhr.responseText)
      return xhr.responseText;
});
```